# Operation on char* may be undefined

Tags: c

I have this code that is warning me

Code :

```
int handle_operation(char *b) {
    char *buf = b;
    uint16_t opcode;
    memcpy(&opcode, buf, 2);
    buf = buf += 2;
}
```

Warning :

```
warning: operation on ‘buf’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
   53 |     buf = buf++;
```

My goal is to increment the buffer's pointer by x each time I memcpy x bytes of it somewhere.

Comment: The code shown does not match the code in the error message. Anyway, change the code to be `buf += 2;`. For more details read the duplicate post.

Comment: @kaylum 3 am code hits hard... wow. Thanks